# Prevent empty data in $_FILES upload

Tags: php

So I've been working on this thing for a few hours now and I'm worn out. When I try and update my contact information, and I choose a picture file it uploads the number 1, to my database, when I don't choose a picture I've succeeded in making the database keep the original picture file.

Can anybody help me figure this one out?

```
if (!empty($_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"]))
{
    $kon_up_path = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["kon_up_path"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampp/htdocs/hansenservice/img/img/site/profil_pics/" . $_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"]);
}
else
{
    $kon_up_path = $kontakt_row['cont_img'];
}
```

Comment: share some code you have tried or so that people can replicate the issue

Comment: please never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever put this code live on a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$kon_up_path = move_uploaded_file(...);
```

`move_uploaded_file()` returns TRUE on success, and FALSE on failure. It does not return a path. If you want the path of the file, use the value you passed as the second argument of `move_uploaded_file()`.

Bonus gotcha: **you need to verify that the provided filename is acceptable**. The code you've provided doesn't show you checking that it has an appropriate extension, doesn't contain any invalid characters, and doesn't already exist. If you're already doing this outside this snippet, great; if not, you need to, lest a user upload a file named `../../../../index.php` (for instance) and blow away your site. Consider generating the filename automatically rather than letting the user specify it at all.

Comment: All i really want is to get the file name, cause when i print it out on the page, i've already provided a path for which folder to go look for that file, that i've just uploaded. In any case what should the code be then?

Comment: nevermind. i figured it out thanks to your answer. Tons of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['kon_up_path']['tmp_name'])) {
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think first print_r($_FILES) the error part contain non zero value so each time it will execute if this will happen then u have to

```
if($_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"]['error'] == 0 ){
   your code 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$kon_up_path = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["kon_up_path"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampp/htdocs/hansenservice/img/img/site/profil_pics/" . $_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"]);
```

`move_uploaded_file()` this function return `false / ture`;

You can do like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["kon_up_path"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampp/htdocs/hansenservice/img/img/site/profil_pics/" . $_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"])){
    $kon_up_path = C:/xampp/htdocs/hansenservice/img/img/site/profil_pics/" . $_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
if (count($_FILES) >= 1)

{
    $kon_up_path = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["kon_up_path"]["tmp_name"],"C:/xampp/htdocs/hansenservice/img/img/site/profil_pics/" . $_FILES["kon_up_path"]["name"]);
}
else
{
    $kon_up_path = $kontakt_row['cont_img'];
}
```

regards